# How to use a substring to extract a sequence and use a while-loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, substring, fasta

I'm very new to coding so excuse any errors!

I need to modify the below script (GC_content.py) with another file as the input (SfPhi01.fasta) to calculate a skew for that input file in Python v2, editing in emacs. I then need to modify it to calculate the skew for 100-base pair segments (biological context) with a step size of 50 base pairs.

I've been given the tips to use a substring to extract sequence from position X to (X+100) and set the initial value of X as 0.
I also need to use a while loop that increases the value of X by 50 and keep calculating as long as X is smaller than the size of the genome minus 100 base pairs.

```
import re

i=0

Input = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
Output = open(sys.argv[1]+'GC_content', 'w')
for line in Input:
     if re.match('>', line):
          if i>0:
              Output.write('\n')
              Output.write(line)
          else:
              Output.write(line)
          i+=1
     else:
        length = float(len(line.replace('\n', '')))
        G = re.subn('G', 'G', line)
        C = re.subn('C', 'C', line)
        G_count = float(G[1])
        C_count = float(C[1])
        GC_content = (G_count + C_count)/length
        Output.write('GC content: '+'\t'+str(GC_content)+'\n')
Input.close()
Output.close()
```

Comment: [Python 2 is very much dead](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/), it was (finally, after far too long a period of uncertainty) abandoned almost a year ago. Please start by switching to Python 3.

Comment: Looks like you trying to find the GC skew from a fasta sequence. Can you show a sequence input and the desired output?